# objectoutputstream java - storing list of objects contain lists of other objects

Tags: java

I know i can store and retrieve objects into files with object output/input stream but im wondering if i can retrieve objects that contain a list of other objects?

ie. Class A has an arraylist of Class B

and that when storing an array of Class A, each of the object holds different sizes of the Class B arraylist.

Do i need to code differently?

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
Obj = (ClassA)ois.readObject();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have implemented Serializable for all classes and sub-classes, you can retrieve all objects even if they are in any collection.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. If you use `java.util.List`, you will be able to write objects. Something like this will perfectly work.

```
class MyTest implements Serializable
{
    List<MySecondTest> list = new ArrayList<MySecondTest>();
    Object obj = Integer.valueOf(1000);
}

class MySecondTest implements Serializable
{
    String str = "Hello, world " + Math.random();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Serialization works over completely arbitrary object graphs including even cyclic ones. A simple list is no problem as long as the collection class is Serializable, as all the JDK ones are.